# Type errors when printing characters with printf

Tags: c, char, printf

I'm trying to save a student's name in a char array and print the first student's name, but my code doesn't work. I'm practicing C, so I'm coding random programs by myself and need help with this one. My code generates the following error:

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'
```

I'm quite new to C. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){



char StudentsName[100];
float StudentsGrades[100];
int NumStudents, i, j;

printf("How many students you want to process? ");
scanf("%d", &NumStudents);
if(NumStudents > 15){goto skip_lines_grades;}

for(i=0; i<NumStudents; i++){

    printf("\n Write the name of the student: ");
    scanf("%s", &StudentsName[i]);

}

//Prints First Student, I'M GETTING THE ERROR HERE, WHY?
printf("%s", StudentsName[0]);

goto skip_last_msg;

skip_lines_grades:;
printf("We can process 15 students for now, try again.");

skip_last_msg:;

}
```

Comment: `char` is *one* character.

Comment: Your array of names is an array of 100 characters, not 100 strings. You want `char StudentsName[100][MAX_NAME_LEN];`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Any fix?

Comment: What is not clear in the warning? You are using the printf format specifier for char pointers (%s) with a char.

Comment: @PepePerez: fix yourself.

Comment: What do you mean? I gave the fix.

Comment: @Étienne "char StudentsName[100]" isn't an integer.

Comment: StudentsName[0] is a char, a char is not printed with %s.

Comment: Sorry, C is so confusing for me, I'm new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you got the basic idea from the discussion above. To summarize, you need to define an array of 100 character variables.

Also, regarding  your error, for `char StudentsName[100];`, `StudentsName[0]` represents the first `char` variable value, not an address, as expected by `%s`. So, your compiler is right. If you need to print a `char`, you need to use `%c` specifier. However, that also is wrong, considering your program logic.

To correct, you can

1. allocate an array of `char [100]` type, to hold more than one student's data.
2. allocate memory dynamically.
3. loop over to take the input for each student.
4. print the output.
5. free the allocated memory.

check the modified code, its self-explanatory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMESIZ 128

int main(){



char *StudentsName[100];   //notice here
float StudentsGrades[100];
int NumStudents, i, j;

printf("How many students you want to process? ");
scanf("%d", &NumStudents);
if(NumStudents > 15){goto skip_lines_grades;}

for(i=0; i<NumStudents; i++){

 StudentsName[i] = malloc(NAMESIZ);                   //notice here
 printf("\n Write the name of the student: ");
 scanf("%s", StudentsName[i]);                        //notice here

}

//for(i=0; i<NumStudents; i++)   //uncomment to print all student data
i = 0;                           //comment out to print all student data
printf("Student [%d] is %s\n", (i+1), StudentsName[i]);

for(i=0; i<NumStudents; i++)
free (StudentsName[i]);                              //notice here

goto skip_last_msg;

skip_lines_grades:;
printf("We can process 15 students for now, try again.");

skip_last_msg:;


}
```

Comment: It might seem self-explanatory to you, but I think this answer would greatly improved by some actual explanations outside the comments explaining exactly the OP did wrong in the first place.